# Does static hosting make S3 bucket overwrite "Block public access" settings for bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a bucket and did not change the default "Block public access" settings. However, I enabled Static web hosting for that bucket. Does this actually overwrite the "Block public access" settings for S3 bucket?

Because the AWS documentation says :

[image]

It's bit ambiguous, any idea on this?  Because my s3 website was accessible when s3 settings was "Block public access".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To test this situation, I did the following:

- Created a new Amazon S3 bucket with default settings
- Uploaded a file to the bucket
- Tested access to the file using a public URL:

  - `https://my-bucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/foo.jpg`
  - Got `Access Denied` (good!)
- Enabled **Static Website Hosting**
- Tested access to the file using the static website URL:

  - `http://my-bucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/foo.jpg`
  - Result: **403 Forbidden** (good!)
- Turned off **S3 Block public access**
- Tested both URLs again

  - Same result (both denied)

Therefore, merely activating Static Website Hosting is **not sufficient** to make the objects public.

**Conclusion**

If your objects were publicly accessible, then it was probably a result of either:

- A **Bucket Policy** making the bucket public, *or*
- Access Control Lists (**ACLs**) on the objects themselves making them public

However, if Block Public Access was enabled on the bucket and objects (as per your picture), then **the objects would not have been public**. In this case, you must not have been accessing the objects via their public (anonymous) URL. This could happen if you click the **Open** or **Download** button in the console, which appends user information. Instead, you should test by using the raw URLs, such as the ones I listed above.